# How can I run emacs for Mac OS X from command line so it opens up in the GUI emacs?

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, emacs

I have installed [“Emacs for Mac OS X”](http://emacsformacosx.com/) on my Mac running Mac OS X 10.6.

How can I run it from a command line to open a file? For example, when I do this:

```
$ emacs aFile.txt
```

It just uses the in-window “Terminal” `emacs`, not the `emacs` from Mac OS X 10.6 that I installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should open it in the UI Emacs:

```
open -a Emacs aFile.txt
```

That works for any Mac application, to get it fired up appropriately.

Comment: Thanks. It works, but when the file does not exit, it said "The file /Users/scheung/a.txt does not exist." how can I make emacs creates a new file name  'aFile.txt' for me?

Answer (score 0):

You have a LOT of options here:

probably the one that will be the least work to get 80% of the possible functionality would be to just prepend `/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/` to your `PATH` variable (in your `.bash_profile` if you don't want to do this manually all the time; I'm assuming you use bash) and invoke the program as Emacs, that way you get the cli behavior you expect when launching emacs, and the gui for the actual editing (to skip the gui use the -nx flag when starting emacs); and then you can also `alias emacs=Emacs` so you don't have to get the case right or change your habits.

another option is to start an emacs daemon (`/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs --daemon`) and pass it files with emacsclient which you can just alias to emacs like `alias emacs="emacsclient -t -s $TMPDIR/emacs$(id -u)/server"`; in addition to this there's the option of starting the daemon from launchd when you login, in case your emacs is slow to start.